# I have issue at install scikit-image with python 3.11 what should I do?

Tags: python, scikit-image

Good evening everyone,

I have an issue with scikit-image while installing this package I installed python 3.11 on windows 11

```
pip install scikit-image
```

I got these issues as below in the screenshot got

[previous issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0zz1.png)

EDIT:

I installed Microsoft C++ 14 but I got another issue at the below screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYFoD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community do you think It's related to windows 11?

Comment: @Community is a bot, it won't respond to you

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for your reply and answer I wrote comment for you please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that no wheels are available for scikit-image for Python 3.11

Python libraries can have code that is not written in Python (like C, C++, FORTRAN, Rust, ...) and in order to use those, you need to compile that code for your version of Python, your OS and CPU architecture.

Fortunately, Python offers a packaging mechanism known as wheel to provide that precompiled code. Package maintainers can generate those wheels to avoid the end user having to compile it from sources.

In your case, as Python 3.11 just got out (beginning of the week), the maintainers of `scikit-image` didn't have the time to package the wheel and pip tries to install it from sources (hence the message asking you to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14).

Your options are:

- stay on Python 3.10 until the maintainers of `scikit-image` provides a wheel for Python 3.11 (I would recommend that)
- check https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image to see how to compile the package from sources

Comment: Yeh that's the first issue I got But I solved it by installing the c++ But I got another one at this image link https://ibb.co/9vpw86L  @Nathan

Comment: No, you didn't solve the first issue by installing the compiler, you are just failing a bit later in the installation from sources. Pip detect that something is lacking and tries to build it from source with default arguments that are not the right one as it can be project specific. Compiling from source is a complicated process (that's why wheels exist) and I unless you absolutely need to use that version of Python immediately, I would just wait for wheels to be released for `scikit-image`: it is currently tracked here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/6517